# Copying all the transform values of a gameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to copy the transform values (position, rotation, scaling) of a gameObject in script. I do not want to copy each transform values separately as given below in the script.

```
public GameObject Obj02;
public GameObject Obj04;
private Vector3 positionOfObj02;
private Vector3 rotationOfObj02;
private Vector3 positionOfObj04;
private Vector3 rotationOfObj04;

void Start()
{
    positionOfObj02 = Obj02.transform.localPosition;
    rotationOfObj02 = Obj02.transform.localEulerAngles;

    positionOfObj04 = Obj04.transform.localPosition;
    rotationOfObj04 = Obj04.transform.localEulerAngles;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried saving it as the same type `Transform`?

Comment: Yes but then I cannot assign it to another GameObject or a Vector3 Gameobject.

Comment: @Eliasar that's not possible in Unity .. `Transform` is a reference-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not built-int but I would recommend a proper type

```
[Serializable]
public class TransformData
{
    public Vector3 LocalPosition = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 LocalEulerRotation = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 LocalScale = Vector3.one;

    // Unity requires a default constructor for serialization
    public TransformData() { }

    public TransformData(Transform transform)
    {
        LocalPosition = transform.localPosition;
        LocalEulerRotation = transform.localEulerAngles;
        LocalScale = transform.localScale;
    }

    public void ApplyTo(Transform transform)
    {
        transform.localPosition = LocalPosition;
        transform.localEulerAngles = LocalEulerRotation ;
        transform.localScale = LocalScale;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
public GameObject Obj02;
public GameObject Obj04;

private TransformData transformDataOfObj02;
private TransformData transformDataOfObj04;

void Start()
{
    transformDataOfObj02 = new TransformData(Obj02.transform);
    transformDataOfObj04 = new TransformData(Obj04.transform);
}
```

and later maybe

```
transformDataOfObj02.ApplyTo(anotherObject.transform);
```

Comment: @derHugo How about making it a `struct`? `Vector3` is a struct anyway, and if these transforms are used extensively (i.e.: create and delete lot of instances), one would avoid GC issues.
I usually use structs when I have a data type that contains only value types inside.

Comment: @Galandil sure why not .. only have in mind that they behave differently. `struct`s are value types while `class`es are reference-types. so with a struct doing `var a = new TransformData(Obj02.transform); var b = a;` copies the values not the reference so later changes will only affect `b`. With a `class` both `a` and `b` would get changed.  In short: It depends on your needs I'ld say.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this: from.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
This moves the whole rotation